# File download issue

Tags: .net, vb.net, download

I have a project which downloads the file from a URL.  It is working downloading file perfectly when I run program from visual studio but when I publish the project to IIS server then it is not being able to download the file and it doesn't give any error as well.  The file should be downloaded to local folder in C which path is hard coded.

I am using downloadFile function in vb. Net.

Comment: whats the file location exactly?

Comment: There must be an error, things rarely just don't work. I would assume it doesn't have access to the path.

Comment: Its all IIS settings. The identity on the pool. The size of request, etc. your question should be directed to some IIS administrators, like "help configuring IIS so file download succeeds"

Answer (score 1):

> the file should be downloaded to local folder in C which path is hard coded.

When you run the program from IIS, you need to think about what *user account* is responsible for this program. It's gonna be a different account than what you used in Visual Studio. Then go to the folder, and make sure that user account has write permissions.

And this problem probably could have been avoided if you were following good practice. It is **NOT** good practice to create and use folders directly underneath the C:\ drive. This is a hold-over from the Windows 98 days, but it's been frowned upon since Windows 2000 and XP came out... more than 15 years now.